# What is @csrf_protect_m in django Why its used?

Tags: django, django-admin

when ever i override the change_view in admin i will get the following line of code

```
@csrf_protect_m
@transaction.commit_on_success
def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    return admin.ModelAdmin.change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=extra_context)
```

What is the First two line of code ?? Should i use this ?? What it does ?

I am just started Extending Django Admin. So hope your answers will be simple and with example.

Comment: It's called decorator, you should have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@csrf_protect_m` is a method decorator.  To understand what its *doing*, read the documentation on [csrf protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/)

`@transaction.commit_on_success` is also a decorator. To understand what its doing, read the documentation on [database transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/?from=olddocs#controlling-transaction-management-in-views)

Decorators in simple terms are a way to wrap conditional functionality around methods or functions. They wrap around a function, modify it, and return the function. The [python manual](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) has an explaination of how they are written.